# сохранения данных в формате XML с приложения Java

Tags: java, xml, javafx, jaxb

Дописал приложение на Java, и собственно следующий шаг - а как сохранять мои данные? Я выбрал формат XML, он прост и насколько я знаю популярен.
В приложении я использую `ObservableList<MainData> contractData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` как основную оболочку для хранения данных. В `MainData` соответственно я храню все переменные и коллекции которые я использую в приложении, так вот, я узнал что XML напрямую не записывает тип `ObservableList`, и необходимо писать класс-обвертку. Я написал, ниже код:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "mainData")
public class DataListWrapper {

    private List<MainData> mainData;

    @XmlElement(name = "mainData")
    public List<MainData> getMainData() {
        return mainData;
    }

    public void setMainData(List<MainData> mainData) {
        this.mainData = mainData;
    }
}
```

И данный класс работает, но дело в том, так как в `MainData` есть не только обычные переменные, но и коллекции типа `ListProperty` он их не сохраняет. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как мне лучше сохранять все мои данные из программы, все находится в `MainData`

Добавлю: Из того, что я понял, мне надо мои геттеры типа `public ListProperty<Attachment> getNameLink(){}` аннотировать `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ListPropertyAdapter.class)` (как-то так). Далее создать класс `ListPropertyAdapter`, в котором будет описано, как `ListPriperty` представлять строковым типом, только вот как...

Мой класс `ListPropertyAdapter`

```
public class ListPropertyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, ListProperty> {

    @Override
    public ListProperty unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return ListProperty.parse(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(ListProperty v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString();
    }
}
```

Не могу заставить работать `unmarshal`

Comment: Вам нужно посмотреть на все это с другой стороны, а именно ЧТО Вам необходимо сохранять в XML. По сути XML для Вас это хранилище данных, соответственно Вам необходимо данные из приложения сохранять в таком виде, чтоб потом их можно было восстановить. А вот классы Java FX - это уже прикладные классы, которые не имеют отношения к предметной области. Итого: Ваш ObservableList<MainData> contractData вы трансформируете в предметный объект и уже его сохраняете в XML. Обратно так же: Берете XML -> Трансформируете в предметный объект -> из него создаете ObservableList<MainData> contractData.

Comment: @ezhov_da соглашусь, я опишу чуть подробнее, я использую в программе `JAXB`, т.е. я произвожу маршаллирование объектов Java в XML и обратно демаршализирую из xml-файла в объекты Java. `JAXB` требует, чтобы внешний класс моих данных был отмечен аннотацией `@XmlRootElement`. Типом переменной `contractData` является `ObservableList`, а его мы не можем аннотировать. Для того, чтобы разрешить эту ситуацию, необходимо создать класс-обёртку, который будет использоваться исключительно для хранения данных, и который мы сможем аннотировать как @XmlRootElement.

Comment: @ezhov_da в общем я так и сделал, но вот как я понимаю коллекции внутри `MainData` тоже необходимо пометить аннотацией, а точнее и им надо сделать обвертку, или как? я не пойму как правильно поступить с коллекциями внутри `MainData` что бы и они сохранялись

Comment: @ezhov_da в общем как мне кажется, я во всем разобрался, мне остается сделать только `unmarshal` для моего `ListProperty`, если Вы можете помочь с этим, буду весьма благодарен, тут я в тупике

Comment: Я в первом комментарии написал, что вы идете неверной дорогой, от этого и трудности. Не нужно сохранять стандартные JavaFX классы, нужно сохранять только Ваши данные.

Comment: @ezhov_da хорошо, значит я не так понял, что бы опять не туда пойти, можно хотя бы простой пример данной трансформации?